# How do you determine which row was selected in a Infragistics WebHierarchicalDataGrid when you have a Master Detail table configuration

Tags: c#-4.0, infragistics

I have a master table and two child detail tables under the master.  When the user selects one of the detail tables the RowSelection event fires.  I need to determine which table was selected.  If the users selectes the second detail table then I need to obtain the data from a specific field.  What code can be put in place to make this determination.  Here is the code I have so far to grab the data, I just need to build the IF statment around this code.

```
            String UploadIndex;

            if (e.CurrentSelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {

                GridRecord oRow = e.CurrentSelectedRows[0];

                UploadIndex = oRow.Items[0].Value.ToString();

            }
```

Tried this but got controlmain is inaccessible due to its protection level.
ContainerGrid oRowIsland = WebHierarchicalDataGrid1.GridView.Rows[e.CurrentSelectedRows[0].Index].RowIslands[0];
                    if (oRow.Owner.ControlMain.ID == '2')
                    {
                        UploadIndex = oRow.Items[0].Value.ToString();
                    }

Answer (score 2):

Use `ContainerGridRecord` type instead of `GridRecord` when declaring oRow, this way you will have access to `oRow.Owner.ControlMain` which is the grid that holds the row. In debug determine ID of the grid you're interested in and then you can do

```
If (oRow.Owner.ControlMain.ID == '...ID of second grid') {
   // profit
}
```

Or use some other easily identifiable property of `ControlMain` grid that in your case assocciate with the second details.

Comment: I am employed full time, so my time will be very limited to consulting and perhaps weekend hours.

Comment: Yuriy, that would work for me.  I have no formal training in programming and taught myself C#.  I am trying to understand all the details of Infragistics but just do not have the level of experience to accomplish some task.  The answer you gave me is way over my head but I am researching each piece of your answer to better understand:)  If nothing else, would you be intrested in remoting in with me and walking me through some problems just to get me over the brick wall that sometimes takes me days to get over?

Comment: Plz contact me yuri@galanter.net to better understand the needs